# Constant scalar curvature Kähler metric and Kähler-Einstein metric

Tags: kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric

Let $(M,g)$ be a Kähler manifold of complex dimension $2$. Suppose $g$ has constant scalar curvature, and the corresponding Ricci form $\rho$ is self-dual (i.e., $* \rho=\rho$).

Can we prove that $(M,g)$ is Kähler-Einstein?